# Sunspot Solr specify offset and limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am aware of how to paginate a solr search via the sunspot gem. But I would like to specify the exact start row and maximum rows to fetch.

For example, something like:

```
Post.search do
  rows(:offset => 2, :limit => 23)
end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like I answered my own question. It can be done like so:

```
Post.search do
  adjust_solr_params do |sunspot_params|
    sunspot_params[:start] = 2
    sunspot_params[:rows] = 23
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Sunspot 1.3.0 (unreleased as of now, but should be released soon) will have an `:offset` parameter to `paginate`: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/commit/2a99fd395a49f4137fd4d2ced0610367ecabf4fe

So you will be able to write something like:

```
paginate(:offset => 2, :per_page => 23)
```